# Showing $\cos(x)-\cos(2x)+\cos(3x)$ has no period smaller than $2\pi$ without calculus?

Tags: fourier-series, alternative-proof, periodic-functions

Let $f(x)=\cos(x)-\cos(2x)+\cos(3x)$. Because each of terms has period dividing $2\pi$, it is straight forward that the sum does too. And by graphing, one can verify that this is the smallest period. But the sum of two functions with a given period can be a smaller period, e.g., $(\cos(x) +\cos(2x)) + (-\cos(x) +\cos(2x))$ has period $\pi$, so something more involved than just knowing the periods of the summands is required to say that the period of the sum isn’t smaller. Is there a simple argument that doesn’t require graphing to show that the period is exactly $2\pi$?  Ideally I would like something that I can explain to a highschooler who does not know calculus.

There is an argument using derivatives that applies to any trigonometric polynomial.  Define the support of a trigonometric sum $f(\theta)=\sum a_k e^{ik\theta}$ to be $\operatorname{supp}(f)=\{k\mid a_k\neq 0\}$.  Suppose that $f(\theta)$ has finite support and period $L$.  Then so does its derivative, and therefore so does $inf(\theta)-f'(\theta)=\sum a_k i(n-k)e^{ik\theta}$, which will have support $\operatorname{supp}(f)\setminus\{n\}$.  By repeating this, eliminating all but a single specified term, we see that $e^{ik\theta}$ has period $L$ for every $k\in \operatorname{supp}(f)$, so $L$ must be a common multiple of the period of each summand.  But any common multiple of the summand periods will be a period of the sum, so the least period of a finite trigonometric sum is the least common multiple of the periods of the summands.  I do not know if this fact holds for general trigonometric sums. If anybody does know, I would be interested in that as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $f(x)=-3$ if and only if $x=(2n+1)\pi$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ (assuming $x\in\mathbb{R}$).  So the least period must be at least $2\pi$.  Combining with $\cos x,\cos 2x,\cos 3x$ all having $2\pi$ as a period then give $2\pi$ as the least period.

Answer (score 1):

We will call a function of minimum positive period $p<\infty$ a period-$p$ function. Let $c:=\cos x$ so $$\cos x-\cos 2x+\cos 3x=c-(2c^2-1)+c(4c^2-3)=(1-2c)(1-2c^2).$$On $[-1,\,1]$, this achieves its minimum of $-3$ only at $-1$ (i.e. $x$ is an odd multiple of $\pi$), leading us to the same logic as in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(\pi)=-3$. For any $p$ with $0<p<2\pi$, we have $\cos(\pi+p)>-1$, hence $f(\pi+p)\ge \cos(\pi+p)-2>-3$.